# Python:On the Comprehensiveness of Python Module Index

Tags: python, module

[3.10.0 Documentation » Python Module Index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html)

[Module names that start with 'w'](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-w)

There are no module names in this list like win32con or win32api, but there are such modules in Python. I became aware of the existence of these modules in Python only accidentally. Isn't this Python Module Index all comprehensive ? Before I thought it is. Now I can see that it is not.
(I am talking about built-in modules of course, not the ones installable by pip).

My question is: Is there such a comprehensive index of modules that can save me from accidental discoveries and surprises? Where can I find this index if there is one ?

With comprehensiveness I mean all-encompassing.I add this because comprehensiveness can also mean 'nearly all'.What I want to say,with comprehensive,is not 'nearly all' but ALL.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Module Index is comprehensive.

Since you're asking whether the Module Index is comprehensive, you should know that win32con and win32api aren't built in, they're from https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

If you want to check where a module is installed, you can do

```
import module_name
print(module_name.__path__)
```

which'll help you understand where the library is from.

Comment: BUT I have never installed pywin32.Can it be that it was installed as a dependency of some other module ?

Comment: win32con.__path__produces AttributeError: module 'win32con' has no attribute '__path__'

Comment: It's just a regular module as far as I know, so it could definitely have been installed that way. Hard to know for sure. Try printing just `win32con` and see what it tells you.